# How can I log the content of a DIV tag?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am making a weather website using Nodejs & HTML. My current code is

```js
function ip() {
    let demo = document.getElementById("demo")
    fetch('https://api.ipify.org/?format=json')
    .then(results => results.json())
    .then(data => demo.innerHTML = data.ip) 
}

ip()
```

What it does, is that it finds the Id of a tag called "demo" and then replaces the content with your IP.

What I am trying to seek help for is how can I make a script/is there a script where it logs the content of that same DIV tag?

Help is appreciated.

Comment: what does "logs" mean?

Comment: `console.log()` ?

Comment: Where do you want it logged?  Also, loading remotely fetched content into the HTML of a site is dangerous.  You can't know for sure if the content is a script or simple text.  You should use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: I want it to be logged in console, e.g. console.log

Comment: Yes, console.log()

Comment: @JosephMarikle Yeah I know but I'm just testing it. And I wanted it to be logged in the console. e.g. `console.log()`

Comment: `.then(data => {console.log(data.ip); demo.innerHTML = data.ip;})`

Comment: @DanMullin Thanks. Is there a way for me to get the region of that IP? I'm using https://ipstack.com/documentation but I don't know how JSON and JS together works.

Comment: These would be what you're looking for I think: `data.continent_code`, `data.continent_name`, `data.country_code`, `data.country_name`, `data.region_code`, `data.region_name`, `data.city`, `data.zip`, `data.latitude`, `data.longitude`

Comment: @DanMullin Yeah, I'm mostly looking for region name & city. I tried doing `console.log(data.region_name)` and it came out with "undefined"

Answer (score 4):

Change the line where you set the innerHTML to include the log statement.

```
.then(data => {
    console.log(data.ip);
    demo.innerHTML = data.ip;
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way for me to get the region of that IP? I'm using ipstack.com/documentation but I don't know how JSON and JS together works

Comment: These would be what you're looking for I think: `data.continent_code`, `data.continent_name`, `data.country_code`, `data.country_name`, `data.region_code`, `data.region_name`, `data.city`, `data.zip`, `data.latitude`, `data.longitude`

Comment: Came out as undefined

Comment: `undefined` for `data.ip` or for the other fields? You can do a check before each one in case the JSON object returned doesn't contain a value for those properties. `if (data.ip != undefined) { // do something }`

Comment: `if (data.region_name != undefined) {...}` When that logs as undefined, do any of the other properties contain data? Do you get the IP for example, but not the region?

Comment: Not for IP, but for data.city etc